# Using grep to remove lines from a file which contain a string from another file

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, sed, awk

I have a file containing words (one per line) such as

> Dog
>  Fish
>  Cat
>  Shoes

I have a secondary file in CSV format such as

> 1,shoes,red
>  2,apple,black
>  3,fog,blue

I would like to use grep with the first file being the search pattern, if a line in the secondary file contains a word in the first file I would like to entirely remove the line in the secondary file.

I am not sure grep is even the way to go about this.

EDIT:
bash scripting

Comment: sed or awk is what you want, not grep.

Comment: How will you handle escaping issues in the csv? This could be a really complex set of regexs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this using `grep`'s `-f` option (that's lower-case `-f`, not `-F`):

```
% echo -e 'Dog\nFish\nCat\nShoes' > ./file1.txt 
% echo -e '1,shoes,red\n2,apple,black\n3,fog,blue' > ./file2.csv 

# Grab all lines from the CSV that match a pattern from file1:
% grep -if ./file1.txt ./file2.csv
1,shoes,red

# Grab all lines from the CSV that DON'T match a pattern from file1:
% grep -vif ./file1.txt ./file2.csv
2,apple,black
3,fog,blue
```

Detailed explanation:

- `grep` — self-explanatory
- `-v` — means 'return lines not matching the input pattern'
- `-i` — means 'use case-insensitive matching' (since your first file had capital letters and the CSV didn't)
- `-f` — means 'interpret each line in the specified file (`file1.txt`) as a pattern to use for matching'

Depending on the results you want and the contents of your files, you may also want to read into the `-F` and `-w` options.

If you need to edit the file in-place, i think you can do this with `sed`'s `-f` option, but `sed` interprets each line of the file as a command rather than a simple pattern like `grep` does.